# A string is said to be lucky if the sum of the ascii values in the string is even.int funcname(char *a) should be used

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int checklucky(char *a);
int iseven(int sum);
int sum(char *a);

int iseven(int sum)
{
   int fin;
   if((sum/2)==0)
      fin=1;
   return fin;
}

int add(char *a)
{
   int i=0,sum=0;
   int len=strlen(a);
   for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
      sum=sum+a[i];
   }
   return sum;
}

int checklucky(char *a)
{
   return iseven(add(a));
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
   char a[100];
   int lucky;
   printf("Enter the input string");
   scanf("%s",a);
   lucky=checklucky(a);
   printf("%s %s lucky\n",a,(lucky==1 ?"is":"is not"));
   return 0;
}
```

The inputs which i give prints only "is not" lucky for all strings.If the sum of ascii values of my strings are even, it should print the given string is lucky else the given string is not lucky. please help me.

Comment: 0)`if((sum/2)==0)`  is wrong. `int iseven(int sum) { return sum % 2==0; }`

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Comment: `int fin;` fin is not initialized

Comment: oops Thank you.i did a very silly mistake.Now it works.

Comment: This [framework](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByXrBuNsq63Ua0x5ak9pU2MzU3M&usp=sharing) might help you with defining what you expect of your functions and debugging your implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Your error was in using the / operator which divides an int and returns the result, instead of the % which divides an int and returns the remainder, thereby returning whether an int is even (if entirely divisible by 2/result is 0) else odd.

```
 int iseven(int sum) {
    int mod = (sum % 2);
    if (mod == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you do not need checklucky() function as it literally accomplishes nothing, at least with your current code.

Comment: BLUEPIXY's comment is correct. You should not post some code without explaining what was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, still new to the editing side of this site

Comment: Thank you all. I got the output.I was new to this site so didn't know how to post and brief it actually. Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to check whether a number is odd or even is:

```
if((sum%2)==0)
```

So, instead of `(sum/2)`, it should be `(sum%2)`.

There is another method to check the same :

```
 if(sum&1)    --->  true if it is odd
 if(!(sum&1))    ---> true if it is even
```

Also, initialize `fin` to `0`. This way, if it doesn't enter the `if` condition, its value is some constant `0`, instead of any arbitrary value like `1`.

The corrected code: http://ideone.com/03ffYW